# How to get values from a string array and assign them to a multi line textbox where all the values are separated with a new line in VB.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, textbox, multiline

I declared a global string array with `Dim Number() as String` and a global string `Dim LineOfText as String`

This is the code where i assign the values of my string array

```
ReDim Number(grdAll.RowCount - 1)
    For j As Integer = 0 To grdAll.RowCount - 1
        LineOfText = (grdAll.Rows(j).Cells(3).Value.ToString() + ",")
        Number = LineOfText.Split(",")
    Next
SMS.Show()
```

Then in my other form this is where i will call the values of my array and assign it to a multi line textbox

```
    For j As Integer = 0 To Number.Length - 1
        For i As Integer = 0 To Number.Length - 2
            txtNumber.Text = Number(i)
        Next i
    Next
```

But i still only get the last value of my array, can anyone help me to assign values of my array to a textbox separated with a new line...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For efficiency, I strongly recommend using [System.Text.StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Dim sbText As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)

For j As Integer = 0 To Number.Length - 1
    For i As Integer = 0 To Number.Length - 2
        ' This will convert the number to a string, add it to the stringbuilder
        ' and then append a newline to the text buffer
        sbText.AppendLine(Number(i))
    Next i
Next
' Now move the buffer into the control
txtNumber.Text = sbText.ToString()
```

Comment: still i only get the last value of my array

Comment: not the exact answer but thanks to your idea, i came up with the right code